# Git diff explanation for sshd

Tags: git, sshd, fuzzing

I have a diff:

```
diff --git openbsd-compat/arc4random.c openbsd-compat/arc4random.c
--- openbsd-compat/arc4random.c
+++ openbsd-compat/arc4random.c
@@ -242,7 +242,7 @@ void
 arc4random_buf(void *buf, size_t n)
 {
        _ARC4_LOCK();
-       _rs_random_buf(buf, n);
+       memset(buf, 0, n);
        _ARC4_UNLOCK();
 }
 # endif /* !HAVE_ARC4RANDOM_BUF */
```

But I don't understand, how exactly do I need to modify the:

https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/crypt/arc4random.c

code to have the exact same as the diff.

Can someone please explain? Or am I looking at the wrong arc4random.c file? Just want to reduce randomness for testing purposes based on: http://www.vegardno.net/2017/03/fuzzing-openssh-daemon-using-afl.html

Comment: I don't understand your question. It appears that the arc4random.c file is already modified. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: [Detailed Description of Unified Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified)

Comment: It's a bit different (file's line do not contain timestamp, and hunk header has suffix which should help human readers to understand a function whre the change is), but the idea is simillar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to [change the line 195](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/93c4e42163484f40e44d2557a7cbc04a27f23da1/lib/libc/crypt/arc4random.c#L195), this is remove the line

```
-       _rs_random_buf(buf, n);
```

And add the line:

```
+       memset(buf, 0, n);
```

(in its place)

The line above and below the changed line are part of the context of the **diff hunk**. See more at "[Unexpected result in git-diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552165/6309)".
That would apply that patch manually to your version of `src/arc4random.c`.

Comment: wow, thanks! but I am still confused why are there lines like:         _ARC4_LOCK(); and         _ARC4_UNLOCK(); etc.

Comment: @Hessnov They are part of the *context* of the diff *hunk. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552165/6309